# Find the 3 Famous Numbers

Tags: mathematics, pattern, poetry

There are 3 clues hidden in the poem below.

Each clue reveals a famous number.

Find the 3 famous numbers and explain your answer in detail.

> By. This. I. reveal three clues displaying
> The relentless nature of numbers.
> I value relationships very much,
> And most, being most beautiful of all,
> The big three first to define relationship like none ever thought of.
>
> Transcend all the preconceived notions and understand.
> Circle back to others.
> Observe what nature makes.
> Border walls are around me, but totally without power to trap.
> Mathematics is very justified in its special veneration of these climbers, indeed, awe- what height!

---

**Edit:**
It's May 7th, so a hint will be given today. I've decided to combine hints 1 and 2 and move directly to the 250 bounty stage. I hope it is the only hint necessary.

Hint #1 is really 9 hints:

> 1. When you find one hidden clue, you will very quickly find the other two.

> 2. Each hidden clue is one sentence.

> 3. There is no riddle tag because the hidden clues are too direct to be good riddle clues.

> 4. No letter manipulation (turning, twisting, reversing, breaking apart, etc.) or assigning of numerical values to letters is necessary.

> 5. No cryptography or ciphering skills are necessary.

> 6. No thesaurus or dictionary will be of help (beyond defining the words in the poem).

> 7. Unlike many riddles, this puzzle involves no (or very little) subjectivity in interpreting the answer.

> 8. You need only the words in the poem. In other words, none of the words need to morph into other words.

> 9. Other than the three periods after the first three words, there is nothing significant about the punctuation in the poem.

Comment: I see several very suspicious words: rot13(genafpraq -> r / cv; pvepyr -> cv ; obeqre -> obeqre bs n fdhner? -> fdhner ebbg bs gjb ; cbjre -> ??? ; eryngvbafuvcf -> engvbany ahzoref? ). Also, rot13("zbfg ornhgvshy bs nyy" vf boivbhfyl gur tbyqra engvb)

Comment: @Stef All great points. You could be onto something. :)

Comment: "Ol. Guvf. V." ybbxf yvxr "cersvk ov. guerr. ebzna ahzreny 1." ohg 231 qbrfa g frrz gb eryngr gb nal snzbhf ahzore (cv: 3.14, r: 2.7, cuv:1.618, fdeg(2): 1.41)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The three famous numbers are

> the golden ratio, *e* and *π*

How to find them:

> As JLee said, it won't be a guess, you have to count the words.
> The first one is the golden ratio, which is 1.6180339887...:
> You take the first word ('By'), then there is the point and then you count to the sixth word ('displaying'), then one word further ('the') and so on, to get:
> ***'By displaying the very, very most beautiful relationship, the others are totally in awe.'***

> The third one is *π*, which is 3.141592653589793...:
> here you take the third word ('I'), then
> there is the point and then you count one ('reveal'), four ('the') and so on to get:
> ***'I reveal the relentless value of the relationship of the circle border to its height.'***

> Thanks to @Rand al'Thor I tried *e* again. I'm so sorry, I must have counted wrong - but nevermind, it's 2.718281828459045... and so we get:
> ***'This relentless nature, and being first to transcend the others, makes me very, very special indeed.'***

Comment: Beginning with 2? Try $e$.

Answer (score 2):

The "big three" would be

> Euler's constant, pi, and the imaginary unit

whose "relationship like none ever thought of" is, of course,

> $e^{i\pi}=-1$

The hints:

> Transcend all the preconceived notions and understand. [e and pi are both transcendental numbers]
>  Circle back to others. [pi is sometimes called the circle constant.]
>  Observe what nature makes. [You use an i to observe. Also, nature likes to make exponential spirals, and $e^{it}$ is a function that generates one.]
>  Border walls are around me, but totally without power to trap. [Another reference to spirals, which encircle a point but enclose no area.]
>  Mathematics is very justified in is veneration of these climbers... [i and pi have climbed on top of e]

Comment: Good try, but I meant the first line of the puzzle very literally: "There are 3 clues hidden in the poem below." The poem below is itself a primary, general clue, but the 3 clues hidden in the poem are specific, direct, and not cryptic.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps AxiomaticSystem is right about the three numbers being

> $e,\pi,i$$,

but the three clues could be more direct inside the poem:

*I value relationships very much,

And most, being most beautiful of all,

The big three first to define relationship like none ever thought of.*

> I feel like this should be something to do with equationd (relationships), defined by an equals sign ($=$), invented by [Robert Recorde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Recorde). If Recorde was the "first to define relationship like none ever thought of" (by introducing the equals sign), then this line might clue $e$ since his name has an extra e compared to the modern English word it resembles.

*Transcend all the preconceived notions and understand.

Circle back to others.*

> This surely indicates $\pi$, a transcendental number which is given by circling.

*Border walls are around me, but totally without power to trap.

Mathematics is very justified in its special veneration of these climbers, indeed, awe- what height!**

> This could be $i$, an imaginary number which is unfettered by inequalities (border walls). The axis of imaginary numbers is drawn vertically, which would make them "climbers", and it goes up to infinity, hence "awe - what height".

It's a bit tenuous, but somehow fits together. Other things I thought of from the poem were

> infinity, from the "relentless nature", and natural numbers, from "what nature makes".

Thinking of different ways of hiding clues, I also tried checking

> letter counts in words, and word counts in phrases/sentences, to see if they spelled out any interesting numbers,

and

> Morse code in full stops and commas, to see if it spelled out anything interesting, but all I got was SETME EEEN(?) which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Another great answer, Rand, but still based only on the general poem clue, and not the 3 hidden clues. From the three clues the answers will be clear. It won't be a guess. I like most your "Thinking of different ways of hiding clues" sections because that is the correct train.

Comment: +1 and 50 bounty because your answer is useful and articulated well, even though it focuses mostly on the general poem clue.